# Rhostudio rhosimulator crash on Mac

Tags: rhomobile, rhodes

I am running on Mac Lion 10.7.3 with i5 2.3 GHz and 4GB Ram.

Application is running fine with command line
    rake run:iphone
    rake run:android

but when I am trying to run the same app using RhoSimulator, app getting crashed just after login.

I looked into all pros and cons but in vain.

First thing first: As the first para of this link suggesting http://docs.rhomobile.com/rhodes/simulator

"RhoSimulator allows to run Rhodes applications without lengthy build process and to debug them in RhoStudio. Currently RhoSimulator works on Windows only."

Is this possible to run rhosimulator on Mac at all?

If yes then please find the [crash report](https://groups.google.com/group/rhomobile/attach/1d8679faf377fc28/rho-simulator-crash.txt?part=4&authuser=0) and throw some light to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

yes , for me too, for no reason, just 1 week before the same application run in rhosimulator but now have got same crash report as you.

but i can login (http async), but after on one page, rhosimulator crash..

-> uninstall all gem rhodes, and multiple packets gems version..
-> reinstall rhodes 3.2.2

-> got same crash.

-> get and install rhosimulator fix pack

-> got same crash

try to compile for iphone simulator, run:iphone-> ok, inside iphone simulator -> got app go out a the same page (crash i suppose)..

so no understand., it's my third application with this framework, i'm tired to patch the framework and try to get stable working framework...